# Browse network in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, network-shares

Is it possible to browse my network with Firefox? This can be done with Windows Explorer, but perhaps it can be done with Firefox, possibly with an existing add-on?

Update: Windows Explorer can show me workstations and servers in my network. This is what I'm mainly looking to get with Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *my Network*?

Comment: The network my computer is connection to, formerly known as `My Network Places` or `Network Neighborhood`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little different from IE.

```
file://///server/myfiles
```

Comment: ahh, but does this work for smb file shares, or just webpages on a windows network?

Comment: Yes it works fine in smb files shares. In my work network i use it all the time.

Comment: @Kalatzis: Thanks, but tried this already, unfortunately it didn't work for me. Plus, in Windows Explorer I can see a list of the computers in my network--this is what I'm primarily after.

Comment: I can't add a photo but in this print screen you can see that it work fine. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77338852/11-6-2012%202-02-11%20%CE%BC%CE%BC.jpg

Comment: @Kalatzis: Thanks again, that does indeed work, as long as I give a directory. If I don't or click on `Up to higher level directory` to get to the root directory, it doesn't do anything.